# [breeze]Server-side MetaData helper

Tags: metadata, breeze, helper

Is there a server-side equivalent of Breeze metadata helper? With the client-side helper, I have to know the model at design time, and keep the code in sync whenever the sever model is updated. This is a big maintenance burden. If there is a server-side helper, I can write generic code that get entity and relationship information at run-time. This not only reduces maintenance work, but also makes the code more reusable.

Comment: Have you ever heard of Entity Framework? : )  You can keep your models in EF and expose them instead of keeping them in two locations.  Perhaps you could write a helper to convert your current models to EF if you aren't using it already.

Comment: There are three server-side metadata generators of which I'm aware: .NET with EF, .NET with NHibernate, and Java with Hibernate.  What server-side technology are you using?

Comment: I am using LightSpeed ORM. It is not compatible with EF. I tried "using EF as a design tool" as suggested in Breeze doc. It didn't work.